# How to get previous latest rows in R Dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tidyverse

I have a below-mentioned dataframe in R.

```
ID     Seq        Value
ID-1   10,055     25
ID-1   10,054     20
ID-1   10,053     45
ID-1   10,052     61
ID-1   10,051     23
ID-2   35,075     19
ID-2   35,074     54
ID-2   35,073     32
ID-2   35,072     77
```

I want to slice the dataframe and fetch only previous latest value basis `Seq` against each `ID`.

Required DF<-

```
ID      Seq      Value
ID-1   10,054     20
ID-2   35,074     54
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your data is already sorted in descending order you can get the 2nd row from each `ID`.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(ID) %>% slice(2)

#   ID    Seq    Value
#  <chr> <chr>  <int>
#1 ID-1  10,054    20
#2 ID-2  35,074    54
```

If it is not change `Seq` to number, sort the data and then extract 2nd row.

```
df %>%
  mutate(Seq = readr::parse_number(Seq)) %>%
  arrange(ID, desc(Seq)) %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  slice(2)
```

Answer (score 1):

A base R option using ´ave`

```
> subset(df, ave(1:nrow(df), ID, FUN = seq_along) == 2)
    ID    Seq Value
2 ID-1 10,054    20
7 ID-2 35,074    54
```

Answer (score 0):

We can also do

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
    group_by(ID) %>%
    filter(row_number() == 2)
```